# How can my ftp change file structure based on new local structure via SVN?

Tags: svn

I have created a webapplication that exists on several sites and if I want to change the file structure, how can I be sure that both the svn-repository and the live server will adopt the changes?

I'm using netbeans to deploy to SVN, the SVN is hosted on springloops.

I think I have an idea but I don't know the final step.

In netbeans I use the **svn->copy to** and create a new folder in the repository. Now I have a new branch.

But if I deploy the new branch, will the ftp server "mirror" it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely dependent on how you have your ftp server set up.  If the remote server is periodically checking the Subversion repo for changes and automatically doing a `svn update`, then any change that you commit to the repo path being monitored should be picked up by the server.  In most cases, the remote server is either set to monitor `/trunk` or a branch with a specific name, like `/deploy`.  Since you're creating a new branch, it's unlikely that the remote server will automatically detect the branch's creation and `switch` its working copy to that branch.  When you complete development and merge that branch back into the trunk (or whichever folder the remote server is monitoring), then the change should get propagated to the remote systems.

If your remote servers are not set up to automatically check for and apply updates from Subversion, then you'll probably need to log into them remotely and do a manual `svn update` in order to pick up the changes.

Comment: I will try it and get back to this answer :)